# Laravel 5.2/jQuery - Access DOM element created with Ajax success, in new change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, laravel-5

I've been coding for years, but only in recent months I started looking into JavaScript/jQuery/Ajax. I have searched for days, but none of the answers I see match what I'm trying to do (as far as I can see).

I have a select that gets a list of agendas from the controller. After an agenda is selected, an Ajax call is triggered to get related subjects from the database, and add it as radio inputs to a predefined div. There is already a radio button group for "time assignment per group", where, depending on your selected option, the right set of input fields is displayed.

This works fine for adding the info, but now I want to edit existing records on this same page. So now I want to select an agenda, get the subjects, have the system check if there are already time assignments for the subject I select. If there are, display the correct fields with the data preloaded. If not, treat it like an Add form.

My select works as expected, the Ajax call also creates the needed radio buttons, but how do I access those newly created radio buttons, to start a new Ajax call on that element, to check if there are already assignments?

**SELECT**

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="agenda" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Agenda</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <select class="form-control" id="agenda" name="agenda">
                <option value="">Selecteer een agenda</option>
                @foreach($agendas as $key => $value)
                    <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<form method="POST" action="{{ action('TimeController@store') }}" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group"><div id="insertSubjects"></div></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="all_type" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Allocatie type</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="radio" name="type" id="user" value="1"> User<br>
            <input type="radio" name="type" id="fraction" value="2"> Fractie<br>
            <input type="radio" name="type" id="oppcoa" value="3"> Oppositie/Coalitie
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="insertFields"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
            <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Voeg toe">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#agenda').on('change', function() {
            var agenda = $('#agenda option:selected').attr('value');
            var my_url = window.location.pathname + '/agenda/' + agenda;

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: my_url,
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('input[name=_token]').val()},
                dataType: 'json',
                context: this,
                success: function (data) {

                    var fields = '<label for="subject" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Selecteer onderwerp</label>' +
                            '<div class="col-sm-6">';

                    jQuery.each(data, function (k, v) {
                        fields += '<input type="radio" name="subject" value="' + v.id + '" class="subject_radio"> ' + v.subject + '<br>';
                    });

                    fields += '</div>';

                    $('#insertSubjects').html(fields);
                    $('input:radio[name=subject]:first').attr('checked', true);
                }
            })
        });

        $('input[type=radio][name=type]').change(function() {
            var fields;
            if (this.id == 'user') {
                fields = '<div class="form-group"><label for="per_user" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Per lid</label><div class="col-sm-6"><input type="text" name="per_user" id="per_user" /></div></div>';
            }
            else if (this.id == 'fraction') {
                fields = '<div class="form-group"><label for="NDP" class="col-sm-3 control-label">NDP</label><div class="col-sm-6"><input type="text" name="NDP" id="NDP" /></div></div>' +
                        '<div class="form-group"><label for="VHP" class="col-sm-3 control-label">VHP</label><div class="col-sm-6"><input type="text" name="VHP" id="VHP" /></div></div>' +
                        '<div class="form-group"><label for="ABOP" class="col-sm-3 control-label">ABOP</label><div class="col-sm-6"><input type="text" name="ABOP" id="ABOP" /></div></div>' +
                        '<div class="form-group"><label for="PL" class="col-sm-3 control-label">PL</label><div class="col-sm-6"><input type="text" name="PL" id="PL" /></div></div>' +
                        '<div class="form-group"><label for="BEP" class="col-sm-3 control-label">BEP</label><div class="col-sm-6"><input type="text" name="BEP" id="BEP" /></div></div>' +
                        '<div class="form-group"><label for="NPS" class="col-sm-3 control-label">NPS</label><div class="col-sm-6"><input type="text" name="NPS" id="NPS" /></div></div>' +
                        '<div class="form-group"><label for="PALU" class="col-sm-3 control-label">PALU</label><div class="col-sm-6"><input type="text" name="PALU" id="PALU" /></div></div>' +
                        '<div class="form-group"><label for="DOE" class="col-sm-3 control-label">DOE</label><div class="col-sm-6"><input type="text" name="DOE" id="DOE" /></div></div>' +
                        '<div class="form-group"><label for="Onbekend" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Onbekend</label><div class="col-sm-6"><input type="text" name="Onbekend" id="Onbekend" /></div></div>';
            }
            else if (this.id == 'oppcoa') {
                fields = '<div class="form-group"><label for="Coalitie" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Coalitie</label><div class="col-sm-6"><input type="text" name="Coalitie" id="Coalitie" /></div></div>' +
                        '<div class="form-group"><label for="Oppositie" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Oppositie</label><div class="col-sm-6"><input type="text" name="Oppositie" id="Oppositie" /></div></div>' +
                        '<div class="form-group"><label for="Neutraal" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Neutraal</label><div class="col-sm-6"><input type="text" name="Neutraal" id="Neutraal" /></div></div>';
            }

            $('#insertFields').html(fields);
        });
    });


</script>
```

All the Ajax requests just return JSON encoded data from the database, but if you guys need to see those calls too, let me know. Please guide me in the right direction...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create array which will hold the newly created radios buttons.

```
var newRdoBtnsArr = []; // Array to hold the newly created new radio buttons

$.ajax({
    .
    .
    .
    .
    success: function (data) {

        var newRdoBtn = '<input type="radio" name="subject" value="' + v.id + '" class="subject_radio"> ';

        newRdoBtnsArr.push( $( newRdoBtn ) ); // Push the radio button as jQuery object

        fields +=  newRdoBtn + v.subject + '<br>';
    .
    .
    .
    .
});
```

**Update after the comment:**

I guess you need to execute a AJAX call when there is a change in newly created radio buttons. In that case you can add below lines and try. Like you did for `$('input[type=radio][name=type]').change(function() {`

```
$( 'body' ).on( 'change', 'input:radio[name=subject]', function() {
    console.log("It works");
} );
```

Comment: And how do i use this `newRdoBtn` in a new Ajax call? After the current Ajax, I tried something like: `$('newRdoBtn').on('change', function() {
                console.log("It works");
            });` to no avail...

Comment: @Stretsh I've updated the answer. Check and let me know

Comment: The `$('body')` part was what I was looking for, that did the trick. I kinda had the feeling it was something this simple... Thanks @ravi-mca